# Proving $\lim \frac{n+6}{n^2-6}=0$ using $\epsilon-\delta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $$\lim \frac{n+6}{n^2-6}=0$$ using $\epsilon-\delta$

Given an $\epsilon >0$, we need to find an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n|<\epsilon$, $\forall$ $n \geq n_0$.

I started with triangle inequality
$$|n^2-6|\leq n^2+6$$
$\implies$
$$\epsilon >\frac{n+6}{n^2-6}\geq \frac{n+6}{n^2+6}$$
$\implies$
$$n^2+6 > \frac{n+6}{\epsilon}$$
$\implies$
$$n^2-\frac{n}{\epsilon}+6-\frac{6}{\epsilon} > 0$$
By Quadratic formula we get
$$n > \frac{1+\sqrt{1+24\epsilon-24\epsilon^2}}{2\epsilon}$$
So we found that $$n_0=\left \lceil \frac{1+\sqrt{1+24 \varepsilon-24 \varepsilon^{2}}}{2 \varepsilon} \right \rceil $$
now we can prove the actual claim backwards. But my doubt is, what if $\epsilon >1$ is chosen?
because when $\epsilon >1$, $1+24\epsilon-24\epsilon^2 <0$

Comment: What is $n$ approaching?

Comment: @cansome I think $\infty$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout, its $\infty$, i think its a standard notation of $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$

Comment: Usually with a limit, you can assume that $\varepsilon$ is "small enough", as long as it is not zero

Comment: If you can find $n_0$ for $\epsilon_1<1$ then obviously for the same $n_0$ you have $|a_n|<\epsilon_1<1<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find $n_1$ such that for any $n> n_1$, $|a_n|<1$.

Hence if $\epsilon > 1$, we can use the same $n_1$ because if $n > n_1$, then we have $|a_n| < 1 < \epsilon$.